# Denumerable sets

Tags: set-theory

I have seen recently the use of "denumerable" to mean one of:

- countably infinite
- countable

Do you condone the use of denumerable to mean any of the above? Which one?

Comment: This is very close to a poll... IMO MO is not a great place for them. In any case, you probably should edit this into community-wiki, for there is not really an *answer* to your question.

Comment: Lang uses denumerable to mean countably infinite in _Algebra_, but I believe that the word was originally synonymous with countable.  

Comment: +1 for being named afer a beloved Star Wars character. :)

Answer (score 12):

Here is a summary of standard parlance in set theory.

- A set is *finite* if it is equinumerous with a natural number. Otherwise, the set is *infinite*.
- A set is *countable* if it is equinumerous with a subset of the natural numbers. (This includes the finite sets.)
- A set is *countably infinite* if it is countable and infinite. This is also called *countably enumerable*.
- A set is *Dedekind finite* if it is not bijective with any proper subset of itself. This is equivalent to the set not containing any countably infinite subset. If the Axiom of Choice holds, it is equivalent to being finite.
- The word *enumerable* is often used with countable sets, but does not by itself imply countability. For example, set theorists often enumerate uncountable sets in a well-ordered sequence. The word *enumeration* carries a connotation of being well-ordered, but this is not strict, since one might enumerate a set by reals, meaning simply to have a surjection from the reals onto the set.
- Some set theorists use *denumerable* synonymously with *countable* (e.g. Moschovakis, Notes on Set Theory, undergraduate textbook). Many or most set theorists seldom use the word *denumerable*. In a quick perusal, I couldn't find use of it in Jech's book Set Theory or Kanamori's book on large cardinals.

Of course, all these concepts originate with Cantor, and I looked up his Contributions to the founding of the theory of Transfinite Numbers (Dover, in translation by Jourdain). I couldn't find the word *denumerable* at all, but Cantor does use *enumerable* at first just to mean countable, but then later extended to include uncountable well-ordered enumerations, as I mentioned above.